# URIs with german special characters don't work (error 404) in Zend Framework 2

Tags: uri, url-routing, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing, url-helper

I want to get a list of cities, where each city name is linked and refers a page for this city:

[image]

The links (created in the view script) look like this:

```
http://project.loc/catalog/Berlin (in the HTML source code url-encoded: Berlin)
http://project.loc/catalog/Erlangen (in the HTML source code url-encoded: Erlangen)
http://project.loc/catalog/Nürnberg (in the HTML source code url-encoded: N%C3%BCrnberg)
```

"Berlin", "Erlangen" etc. work, but if the city name contains a german special character (`ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `Ä`, `Ö`, `Ü`, or `ß`) like "Nürnberg", a 404 error occurs:

> A 404 error occurred Page not found. The requested URL could not be
>   matched by routing. No Exception available

Why? And how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

My router settings:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'catalog' => array(
            'type'  => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/catalog',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                    'action'     => 'list-cities',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'city' => array(
                    'type'  => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/:city',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'city'  => '[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                            'action'     => 'list-sports',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                    // ...
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Isn’t it obvious, that this does not match the `constraints` you’ve defined?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've just edited the router settings. It's still not working.

Comment: You showed what the URLs “look” like – but did you use proper URL encoding for this special characters?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm set the cities names to the URI so how they are comming from the database (`$city->name` and not `urlencode($city->name)`).

Comment: If you don’t urlencode special characters in URLs yourself, then you leave that up to the client – and with that you can easily run into problems with the character encoding used.

Comment: If I would use `urlencode($city->name)`, I would get URIs like `/catalog/N%25C3%25BCrnberg` instead of `/catalog/Nürnberg`.

Comment: No, `%25C3%25BC` would be `ü` url-encoded _twice_ – `%C3%BC` would be correct for an `ü` in UTF-8. And modern browsers will still _display_ this as `ü` in the status bar/address bar. If you _don’t_ url-encode special chars properly, you might run into problems with a browser assuming a different character encoding than UTF-8 and encode it as f.e. an ISO-8859-1 `ü`, which would be just `%FC` … and then you will _really_ run into problems with your routing.

Comment: I've taken a look into the HTML code. Actually, the URIs is url-encoded (`/catalog/N%C3%BCrnberg`), ZF does it by default. I didn't know it and provided you with wrong information, sorry. Also, the URI is url-encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your constraints, you can use a regular expression which will match UTF8 characters, something like this:

```
'/[\p{L}]+/u'
```

Notice the /u modifier (unicode).

EDIT:

The problem is [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660197/2019043).

Explanation:

The RegEx Route maches the URIs with `preg_match(...)` (line [116](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Regex.php#L116) or [118](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Regex.php#L118) of Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex). In order to mach a string with "special chars" (128+) one must pass the pattern modifier `u` to `preg_match(...)`. Like this:

```
$thisRegex = '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}]*)';
$regexStr = '(^' . $thisRegex . '$)u'; // <-- here
$path = '/catalog/Nürnberg';
$matches = array();
preg_match($regexStr, $path, $matches);
```

And since RegEx Route passes a url-enccoded string to `preg_match(...)`, it's furthermode needed to decode the string first:

```
$thisRegex = '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}]*)';
$regexStr = '(^' . $thisRegex . '$)u';
$path = rawurldecode('/catalog/N%C3%BCrnberg');
$matches = array();
preg_match($regexStr, $path, $matches);
```

These two steps are not provided in the RegEx Route, so that `preg_match(...)` gets a steing like `'/catalog/N%C3%BCrnberg'` and tries to mach it to a regex like `'/catalog/(?<city>[\\p{L}]*)/u'`

The **solution** is to use a custom RegEx Route. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660197/2019043) is an example.

Comment: Thank you! That doesn't work for me, but maybe I'm using your regex wrongly. I've replaced `'city'  => '[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9_-]*',` with `'city'  => '/^\p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+$/u',`

Comment: maybe that was a poor example, it was just to ullustrate the /u flag. try '/[\p{L}]+/u'

Comment: Its finally working! Thank you for so important hint at the modifier!

Comment: I've already posted the explanation and a link to the solution as completion to your answer. What do you mean?

Comment: I added this to my modifier: /[\p{L}]+/u but not working still. Automatix, can you please share what you have used?