# How to set a (UTF8) modifier for RegEx of a RegEx Route in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, pcre, modifier

I'm having [troubles with (german) special characters in URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634913/uris-with-german-special-characters-dont-work-error-404-in-zend-framework-2) and want to try to resolve it with a [RegEx Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex) and a [PCRE pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for UTF-8 `u`.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        // ...
        'city' => array(
            'type'  => 'regex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[a-zA-Z0-9_-äöüÄÖÜß]*)\/u',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                    'action'     => 'list-sports',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/catalog/%city%',
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ),
    ),
),
```

But when I set it, the route stopps to work at all (error 404) -- neither for URIs with nor to ones without special characters.

How to set the modifier correctly?

Comment: actually I think there's a problem with the regex router not allowing the modifier

Comment: Didn't you say yesterday ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636028/2019043)), I need to use the UTF-8 modifier in order to get the URI with spacial char working?

Comment: Yes as your regex wouldn't work, but i've just looked at the code inside the router and I think it's not gtoing to work with the modifier I supplied using regex router :(

Comment: The problem as I see it is that the path evaluated by the Regex route is rawurlencoded, and isn't rawurldecoded until *after* it's evaluated against the regex, so it's never going to match your character list. In addition, you can't pass a modifier to be appended to the regex, so the result of your regex above will be `preg_match('(^/catalog/(?<city>[a-zA-Z0-9_-äöüÄÖÜß]*)\/u$)', $path, $matches);` which is not what you wanted. You may have to write your own regex route handler to solve this.

Comment: Exactly. I've just debugged the RegEx Route (Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex). It's the [line 118](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Regex.php#L118), where the matching takes place. The first argument passed to `preg_match(...)` is `'(^' . $this->regex . '$)'` and `$this->regex` is equal to the string the `regex` option is set to.

Comment: see if my answer below resolves it, it's working locally for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I already had this open here's a handler that solves the problem.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Mvc\Router\Http;

use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;

class UnicodeRegex extends Regex
{
    /**
     * match(): defined by RouteInterface interface.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  integer $pathOffset
     * @return RouteMatch
     */
    public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
    {
        if (!method_exists($request, 'getUri')) {
            return null;
        }

        $uri  = $request->getUri();
        // path decoded before match
        $path = rawurldecode($uri->getPath());

        // regex with u modifier    
        if ($pathOffset !== null) {
            $result = preg_match('(\G' . $this->regex . ')u', $path, $matches, null, $pathOffset);
        } else {
            $result = preg_match('(^' . $this->regex . '$)u', $path, $matches);
        }

        if (!$result) {
            return null;
        }

        $matchedLength = strlen($matches[0]);

        foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key) || is_int($key) || $value === '') {
                unset($matches[$key]);
            } else {
                $matches[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return new RouteMatch(array_merge($this->defaults, $matches), $matchedLength);
    }
}
```

Assuming you place the file in `Application/Mvc/Router/Http/UnicodeRegex` your route definition should look like this

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        // ...
        'city' => array(
            'type'  => 'Application\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}]+)',
                // or if you prefer, your original regex should work too
                // 'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[a-zA-Z0-9_-äöüÄÖÜß]*)',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                    'action'     => 'list-sports',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/catalog/%city%',
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Having currently a very similar issue with the `Segment` route. As your solution worked so well, could you please take a look. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd like to make it possible to also use a % character.. What do you advice to add to the regex? Simply adding % or \% before or after \p{L} doesn't work..

Comment: Hmm, did not need that % char to match.. Wanted to match a whitespace URL encoded, but ZF2 let the regex match against urldecoded string.

Comment: I've filed this [as a bug in the ZF2 issue trackeg](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/7335). A subscribe there might help get this fixed upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I guess you can solve it as easily as many other ones had this same problem. So take a look at some of them:

### [UTF-8 in * regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408143/2215452)

There uses the following modifiers like `\\s`, `\\p{L}`, and `\\u` to help you. I hope it solves! Good luck.

**Edit**

See my own test:

```
<?php

    $toss_the_dice = utf8_decode ("etc/catalog/Nürnberg");
    preg_match ('/\/catalog\/([\\s\\p{L}]*)/m', $toss_the_dice, $dice);
    echo utf8_encode ($dice[1]);

// Now it prints
// Nürnberg

?>
```

Can you realize?

**Edit 2**

It can be better for you!

```
<?php
    $toss_the_dice = "etc/catalog/Nürnberg";
    preg_match ('/\/catalog\/([\\s\\p{L}]*)/u', $toss_the_dice, $dice);
    echo $dice[1];

// Now it also prints
// Nürnberg

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I've asked about is: how to set it **in this concret context of ZF2 RegeEx Route settings** -- and not in general! I have set it like this: `'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[a-zA-Z0-9_-äöüÄÖÜß]*)\/u',`, it hasn't worked, so my question is: how to add the UTF-8 modifier to my `'/catalog/(?<city>[a-zA-Z0-9_-äöüÄÖÜß]*)'` so, that it works?

Comment: You're welcome, mate. So, I think it should be solved without "Zend" ones. For instance, I meant you should replace the "äöüÄÖÜß" for the properly way. It all concerns RegEx patterns. Did you try to apply **\\p{L}** on it?

Comment: I've tried this out: `'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}]*)',` It works for "Berlin", but doen't work for "Nürnberg".