# Route mit special characters are not parsed correctly in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404, zend-route, zend-router

URIs with german special characters don't work (error 404). I've already had this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634913/uris-with-german-special-characters-dont-work-error-404-in-zend-framework-2)) and it has been resolved with the [unicode modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636028/2019043) and a [custom view helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660197/2019043), that uses it.

Now I have the same issue with a `Segment` child route, but this time the approach with the unicode identifier and a custom view helper isn't working.

Alle requests like `sld.tld/sport/sportäöüÄÖÜß/cityäöüÄÖÜß` or `sld.tld/sport/sportäöüÄÖÜß/cityäöüÄÖÜß/page/123` are ending with a `404` error.

**/module/Catalog/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'catalog' => array(
                ...
            ),
            'city' => array(
                ...
            ),
            // works correctly, if I remove the child route
            'sport' => array(
                'type'  => 'MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex',
                'options' => array(
                    'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)/(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                        'action'     => 'list-courses',
                    ),
                    'spec'  => '/catalog/%city%/%sport%',
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'courses' => array(
                        'type'  => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '[/page/:page]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                                'action'     => 'list-courses',
                            ),
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

I've also tried it with a `UnicodeRegex` child route:

```
        'sport' => array(
            'type'  => 'MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/catalog/(?<city>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)/(?<sport>[\p{L}\p{Zs}]*)',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                    'action'     => 'list-courses',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/catalog/%city%/%sport%',
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'courses' => array(
                    'type'  => 'MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex',
                    'options' => array(
                        'regex' => '/page/(?<page>[\p{N}]*)',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Catalog\Controller\Catalog',
                            'action'     => 'list-courses',
                        ),
                        'spec'  => '/page/%page%',
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ),
            )
        ),
```

**UnicodeRegex**

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660197/2019043)

**UnicodeSegment**

Extends `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment` and completes the input of ALL `preg_match(...)` calls with `u`:

- [`'((\G(?P<literal>[^:{\[\]]*)(?P<token>[:{\[\]]|$)))u'`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L157)
- [`'(\G\{(?P<name>[^}]+)\}:?)u'`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L167)
- [`'((\G(?P<name>[^:/{\[\]]+)(?:{(?P<delimiters>[^}]+)})?:?))u'`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L173)
- [`'(\G(?P<literal>[^}]+)\})u'`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L182)
- [`'(\G' . $this->regex . ')u'`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L353)
- [`'(^' . $this->regex . '$)u'`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L355)

How to get it working?

Comment: I've filed this [as a bug in the ZF2 issue trackeg](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/7335). A subscribe there might help get this fixed upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had a look at this, you need to change the `UnicodeRegex` match method so that it returns the correct length for the part of the url it matched, here's an attempt to fix that, which seems to be working (at least for me) with your setup

```
public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
{
    if (!method_exists($request, 'getUri')) {
        return null;
    }

    $uri  = $request->getUri();
    $path = rawurldecode($uri->getPath());

    if ($pathOffset !== null) {
        $result = preg_match('(\G' . $this->regex . ')u', $path, $matches, null, $pathOffset);
    } else {
        $result = preg_match('(^' . $this->regex . '$)u', $path, $matches);
    }

    if (!$result) {
        return null;
    }

    foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($key) || is_int($key) || $value === '') {
            unset($matches[$key]);
        } else {
            $matches[$key] = rawurldecode($value);
        }
    }

    // at this point there's a mismatch between the length of the rawurlencoded path
    // that all other route helpers use, so we need to match their expectations
    // to do that we build the matched part from the spec, using the matched params 
    $url = $this->spec;
    $mergedParams = array_merge($this->defaults, $matches);
    foreach ($mergedParams as $key => $value) {
        $spec = '%' . $key . '%';
        if (strpos($url, $spec) !== false) {
            $url = str_replace($spec, rawurlencode($value), $url);
        }
    }
    // make sure the url we built from spec exists in the original uri path
    if (false === strpos($uri->getPath(), $url)) {
        return null;
    }
    // now we can get the matchedLength
    $matchedLength = strlen($url);

    return new RouteMatch($mergedParams, $matchedLength);
}
```

Comment: I've just tried it out without `UnicodeSegment` -- and it's still working... Don't ALL routes used for the request need to be "unicode safe"?

Comment: only if you're applying unicode constraints to the params in the segment itself, otherwise it's not necessary

Comment: What version of ZF2 is this modification set against? [I've run into pretty much the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29097676/313192) but this code does not work for me and I havn't been able to figure out what bits to port to work against 2.3.5.