# How can I make the Segment router sanely process constraints in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, preg-match, zend-route, turkish

I'm using the [Segment router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment) as a [child](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#treeroutestack) of one of my main [Literal routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-literal) in a ZF2 (currently using 2.3.5) application. The router needs to be able to handle Turkish input characters coming in from the URL. My first attempt looked something like this (as a child route):

```
'book' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'kitap/:book[/]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'book' => '[a-zA-ZçÇşŞğĞıİöÖüÜ1-3.+ ]+',
        ),
    ),
),
```

This mostly worked for everything I needed it to: upper and lower-case letters, numbers up to 3, etc. Then I noticed it wasn't accepting Turkish capital [dotted i's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) (İ) so I started checking. It actually isn't accepting any Turkish characters at all even though the rest of the bits seem to be processed properly.

Even using `\w+` does not seem to match (locale not set to Turkish?), but using `\S+` does so the router doesn't have a problem with Turkish URLs, it's just the matching that's whacked.

I looked through [the source code for the Segment router](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php) and it [appears](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L372) to be using `preg_match()`, which should handle this just fine. What am I missing here?

**Edit**:  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15658354/313192) is about the same problem, but in the Regex router. [This even more closely related one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16097053/313192) deals with the same issue in the Segment router and is nearly a duplicate, but it does not solve my problem as the code demonstrated is against an old version of ZF2 and is neither a drop in match, nor was I able to port it to work against the updated upstream module which appears to handle things a bit differently. I've also [filed an upstream bug report](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/7335) hoping this gets fixed there, but I'm still left without a currently working module. I am happy to create a replacement module for my project with this function patched but am not able to figure out the changes to make it work.

Comment: Any reason for not using the u modifier? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @StevenGeorge I know about the `u` modifier, but how do I use it in this context? Without modifying the `vendor/*` code (which is installed on the server, not part of my project), my code is not responsible for setting PCRE modifiers. What is the proper way to do this inside a site based on ZF2?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658354/how-to-set-a-utf8-modifier-for-regex-of-a-regex-route-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: @sq Thanks. That's useful, but see my edit as that does not quite get me to a solution.