# ZF2 Routing with Special Characters

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I have a little question regarding the routing with Zend Framework 2. URLs with "normal" letters are working fine and I get to my sides, but for example an URL with characters like á or whitespaces `/test/some characters` `/test/héllo` won't work and I get a 404-Error. When I remove the whitespaces in the url or replace the special character é with normal "e" I will get my url too.

So I think the problem is in my module.config.php with the constraints. How can I define these special characters to reach the URLs? Hope you can help me!

module.config.php URL Segment

```
'chemistry' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '[/:id[/:name]]/chemistry/page[/:page]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'id'    => '[0-9]*',
            'name'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*',
            'page'  => '[0-9]*'
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'action'=> 'chemistry',
            'id'    => '1',
            'name'  => 'Messi',
            'page'  => '1'
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097053/route-mit-special-characters-are-not-parsed-correctly-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: Thanks for the link, but didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a regex in your route constraints. If you want to match route segments like that you should change your regex constraint accordingly. So if you want to match a route segment with a space character you have to add it to your regex:

- To match spaces anywhere in the segment:

  `'[a-zA-Z ]+'`
- To match words with spaces in between.

  `'[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*'`

You can read more on Regex in routing here in the paragraph [`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex) in chapter [`Routing`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#routing)

Comment: The first one was on my mind too, but didn't work for me. Also your second suggestion failed :/