# Zend framework why this url not working which has a spanish character?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

When i visit the url as `http://www.example.com/Formación`
then the routing should match, but its not working because i have a character `ó`, how to make this `ó` spanish characters compatible with the following routing in ZF?

```
$route = Http\Segment::factory(array(
  'route' => '/Formación',  //<<<<< this character must be used: ó
  'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Trainingsignup',
    'action' => 'index'
  ),
));
$router->addRoute('traininges', $route, null);
```

EDIT: failed following too

```
  'constraints' => array(
      'controller' => '[a-zA-ZóäöüÄÖÜß][a-zA-ZóäöüÄÖÜß0-9_-]+',
      'action'     => '[a-zA-ZóäöüÄÖÜß][a-zA-ZóäöüÄÖÜß0-9_-]+',
  ),
```

EDIT: failed following too

```
  'constraints' => array(
      'controller' => '/^\p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+$/u',   //or /[\p{L}]+/u
      'action'     => '/^\p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+$/u',   //or /[\p{L}]+/u
  ),
```

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634913/uris-with-german-special-characters-dont-work-error-404-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: I think that is not same issue i have, he is talking about action but in my case its static controller.

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097053/route-mit-special-characters-are-not-parsed-correctly-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: @Wilt: that is also not valid reference, because he is not using "Http\Segment" but `'type'  => 'MyNamespace\Mvc\Router\Http\UnicodeRegex',` . Mine is a STATIC url, others were using Dynamic with.

Comment: All the examples are using Dynamic catch, i have static "/Formación" but others had like `/Formación/:itsalready-toolate-here-because-my-character is static in first block`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15658622/285594 - tried this too, but not working.

Comment: Another recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10600577/1105871

Answer (score 0):

My honest answer would be: DONT DO IT - Please use just ASCII.

But if you really want: [How to set a (UTF8) modifier for RegEx of a RegEx Route in Zend Framework 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658354/how-to-set-a-utf8-modifier-for-regex-of-a-regex-route-in-zend-framework-2/15660197#15660197)